# Count number of attempts, and ask user to play again loops. C#

Tags: c#, loops

I am making a guess the number game and at the end of the I would like to tell the user how many attempts it took to guess the correct answer. I also want to be able to ask the user if they would like to play again. I'm pretty new to this and I'm just kind of struggling trying to figure out how to do this. If anyone could help out with it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void Play()
{
  HiLow hi = new HiLow();
  int number = hi.Number;
  int guess;

  for (guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "); guess != number; guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "))
  {
    if (guess < number)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Higher");
    }
    else if (guess > number)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Lower");
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("You win! {0} was the correct number!", number);
}
```

Comment: show your `PromptForInt` function

Comment: I would use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop: `while (guess != number) { guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "); if (guess < number) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to define a `counter` to store user attempts, and you can put your for loop inside of `while(true)` so you can ask user if they want to play again after `for` loop:

```
while(true)
{
    int attempts = 0;
    for(...)
    {
         if (guess < number)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Higher");
             attempts++;
         }
         else if (guess > number)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Lower");
             attempts++;                  
         }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You win! {0} was the correct number! your attempts: {1}", number, attempts);
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again ? (y / n)");

    if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "y") break;

}
```

Comment: Need to put attempts=0 inside the while.

Comment: would I put my other variables inside the while loop for the for loop?

Comment: @user3475011 you can keep the outside of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
public void Play()
        {
           HiLow hi = new HiLow();
           int number = hi.Number;
           int guess;
   int attempts=0;

           for (guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "); guess != number; guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "))
           {
               if (guess < number)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Higher");
               }
               else if (guess > number)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Lower");                  
               }
attempts++;
           }
           Console.WriteLine("You win! {0} was the correct number!", number);
        }
```

You can then output 'attempts' to tell them how many tries.

At this point, to give them the option to play again, best leave Play() alone and put the logic for replay in whatever calls Play (because Play is a nice implementation of a single play, no need to complicate it).

```
void PlayGame(){

  while(UserNoWantToQuit()){
    Play();
  }

 }
```